# Issue with using ksoap jar, when install my app on a real android device

Tags: android, ksoap

I have a problem with my android application.
That application which uses the kSOAP jar, in order to make connection with a webservice.

In the eclipse emulator everything works fine.
But when I extract the apk and install it on a real device, the application says that there isn't installed.

If I remove the kSOAP, I can open the application.

What should I do?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved.

The problem was related to the use of: android:permission = "INTERNET", on every Activity.
And related to when i export the apk, i was not include the kSOAP jar.

My bad.