# Android app doesn't run on my tablet

Tags: android, eclipse, installation, android-2.1-eclair

I develop one app for android, on eclipse. It works in the emulator, very well. It works too, in a boston mobile, with 2.1 version but when I install the app on my tablet (3.2.1) says didn't was installed.

I can't understand why. Can you help me?

The AndroidManifest file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="BIQ.ERP"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" /><application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET">
        <activity android:name=".BIQActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" android:label="@string/app_name" android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Menu" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" android:label="@string/app_name" android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".InsertHoras" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" android:label="@string/app_name" android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".InsertDespesas" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" android:label="@string/app_name" android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Mapa" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" android:label="@string/app_name" android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Perfil" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" android:label="@string/app_name" android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And the LogCat is:

```
03-26 18:21:22.100: D/dalvikvm(1093): GC_EXPLICIT freed 248K, 5% free 7060K/7367K, paused 7ms+2ms
03-26 18:21:23.430: D/AndroidRuntime(1164): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
03-26 18:21:23.430: D/AndroidRuntime(1164): CheckJNI is OFF
03-26 18:21:23.540: D/AndroidRuntime(1164): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
03-26 18:21:23.550: D/AndroidRuntime(1164): Shutting down VM
03-26 18:21:23.550: I/AndroidRuntime(1164): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
03-26 18:21:23.550: D/dalvikvm(1164): GC_CONCURRENT freed 99K, 87% free 339K/2560K, paused 0ms+0ms
03-26 18:21:23.550: D/jdwp(1164): adbd disconnected
03-26 18:21:23.550: D/jdwp(1164): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
03-26 18:21:23.550: D/dalvikvm(1164): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
03-26 18:21:23.830: D/AndroidRuntime(1175): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
03-26 18:21:23.830: D/AndroidRuntime(1175): CheckJNI is OFF
03-26 18:21:23.960: D/AndroidRuntime(1175): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
03-26 18:21:24.000: D/dalvikvm(1067): GC_EXPLICIT freed 4K, 5% free 6307K/6595K, paused 2ms+2ms
03-26 18:21:24.000: D/PackageParser(142): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl202318575.tmp
03-26 18:21:24.000: W/ActivityManager(142): No content provider found for: 
03-26 18:21:24.000: W/ActivityManager(142): No content provider found for: 
03-26 18:21:24.040: D/PackageManager(142): Scanning package BIQ.ERP
03-26 18:21:24.040: I/PackageManager(142): Unpacking native libraries for /data/app/BIQ.ERP-1.apk
03-26 18:21:24.080: D/dalvikvm(1184): DexOpt: 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
03-26 18:21:24.080: D/dalvikvm(1184): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlParser;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
03-26 18:21:24.080: D/dalvikvm(1184): DexOpt: 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlSerializer;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
03-26 18:21:24.080: D/dalvikvm(1184): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlSerializer;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
03-26 18:21:24.080: D/dalvikvm(1184): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Node;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
03-26 18:21:24.080: D/dalvikvm(1184): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Document;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
03-26 18:21:24.080: D/dalvikvm(1184): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Element;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
03-26 18:21:24.080: D/dalvikvm(1184): DexOpt: 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
03-26 18:21:24.080: D/dalvikvm(1184): DexOpt: 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserFactory;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
03-26 18:21:24.110: I/dalvikvm(1184): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
03-26 18:21:24.110: I/dalvikvm(1184): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
03-26 18:21:24.110: I/dalvikvm(1184): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
03-26 18:21:24.110: I/dalvikvm(1184): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
03-26 18:21:24.110: I/dalvikvm(1184): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
03-26 18:21:24.110: I/dalvikvm(1184): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
03-26 18:21:24.110: I/dalvikvm(1184): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
03-26 18:21:24.120: I/dalvikvm(1184): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
03-26 18:21:24.120: I/dalvikvm(1184): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
03-26 18:21:24.120: I/dalvikvm(1184): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlSerializer;'
03-26 18:21:24.120: D/dalvikvm(1184): DexOpt: not verifying/optimizing 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;': multiple definitions
03-26 18:21:24.120: D/dalvikvm(1184): DexOpt: not verifying/optimizing 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlParser;': multiple definitions
03-26 18:21:24.120: D/dalvikvm(1184): DexOpt: not verifying/optimizing 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlSerializer;': multiple definitions
03-26 18:21:24.120: D/dalvikvm(1184): DexOpt: not verifying/optimizing 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlSerializer;': multiple definitions
03-26 18:21:24.120: D/dalvikvm(1184): DexOpt: not verifying/optimizing 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Node;': multiple definitions
03-26 18:21:24.120: D/dalvikvm(1184): DexOpt: not verifying/optimizing 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Document;': multiple definitions
03-26 18:21:24.120: D/dalvikvm(1184): DexOpt: not verifying/optimizing 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Element;': multiple definitions
03-26 18:21:24.120: I/dalvikvm(1184): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException;'
03-26 18:21:24.130: D/dalvikvm(1184): DexOpt: not verifying/optimizing 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException;': multiple definitions
03-26 18:21:24.130: D/dalvikvm(1184): DexOpt: not verifying/optimizing 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserFactory;': multiple definitions
03-26 18:21:24.130: D/dalvikvm(1184): DexOpt: load 7ms, verify+opt 48ms
03-26 18:21:24.180: D/PackageManager(142):   Activities: BIQ.ERP.BIQActivity BIQ.ERP.Menu BIQ.ERP.InsertHoras BIQ.ERP.InsertDespesas BIQ.ERP.Mapa BIQ.ERP.Perfil
03-26 18:21:24.180: I/ActivityManager(142): Force stopping package BIQ.ERP uid=10090
03-26 18:21:24.310: D/PackageManager(142): New package installed in /data/app/BIQ.ERP-1.apk
03-26 18:21:24.440: D/GTalkService(262): [GTalkService.1] handlePackageInstalled: re-initialize providers
03-26 18:21:24.460: D/AccountTypeManager(672): Registering external account type=com.linkedin.android, packageName=com.linkedin.android
03-26 18:21:24.460: D/GTalkService(262): [RawStanzaProvidersMgr] ##### searchProvidersFromIntent
03-26 18:21:24.480: D/AccountTypeManager(672): Registering external account type=com.skype.contacts.sync, packageName=com.skype.raider
03-26 18:21:24.490: D/PackageManager(142): generateServicesMap(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator): 9 services unchanged
03-26 18:21:24.520: W/ResourceType(672): getEntry failing because entryIndex 1285 is beyond type entryCount 185
03-26 18:21:24.520: D/PackageManager(142): generateServicesMap(android.content.SyncAdapter): 20 services unchanged
03-26 18:21:24.530: W/ResourceType(672): Failure getting entry for 0x7f020505 (t=1 e=1285) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
03-26 18:21:24.530: W/ResourceType(672): getEntry failing because entryIndex 1286 is beyond type entryCount 185
03-26 18:21:24.530: W/ResourceType(672): Failure getting entry for 0x7f020506 (t=1 e=1286) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
03-26 18:21:24.530: W/ResourceType(672): getEntry failing because entryIndex 1287 is beyond type entryCount 185
03-26 18:21:24.530: W/ResourceType(672): Failure getting entry for 0x7f020507 (t=1 e=1287) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
03-26 18:21:24.530: W/ResourceType(672): getEntry failing because entryIndex 1680 is beyond type entryCount 185
03-26 18:21:24.530: W/ResourceType(672): Failure getting entry for 0x7f020690 (t=1 e=1680) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
03-26 18:21:24.530: D/AccountTypeManager(672): Registering external account type=com.twitter.android.auth.login, packageName=com.twitter.android
03-26 18:21:24.570: D/UploadsManager(1108): collect new photo: MediaTracker:**************************,trackNew:photo-external,36057:photo-phoneStorage,-1:video-external,0:video-phoneStorage,-1
03-26 18:21:24.570: D/dalvikvm(672): GC_CONCURRENT freed 553K, 9% free 6913K/7559K, paused 2ms+3ms
03-26 18:21:24.590: W/ResourceType(672): getEntry failing because entryIndex 207 is beyond type entryCount 185
03-26 18:21:24.610: W/ResourceType(672): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0200cf (t=1 e=207) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
03-26 18:21:24.610: D/AccountTypeManager(672): Registering external account type=com.facebook.auth.login, packageName=com.facebook.katana
03-26 18:21:24.640: W/ResourceType(672): getEntry failing because entryIndex 280 is beyond type entryCount 185
03-26 18:21:24.640: W/ResourceType(672): Failure getting entry for 0x7f020118 (t=1 e=280) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
03-26 18:21:24.750: I/AccountTypeManager(672): Loaded meta-data for 7 account types, 6 accounts in 23ms
03-26 18:21:24.750: D/UploadsManager(1108): collect new video: MediaTracker:**************************,trackNew:photo-external,36057:photo-phoneStorage,-1:video-external,0:video-phoneStorage,-1
03-26 18:21:24.770: V/PicasaContentProvider(1108): querySettings: defaults: {sync_on_wifi_only=1, auto_upload_account_type=null, sync_on_battery=1, sync_picasa_on_wifi_only=1, auto_upload_enabled=0, video_upload_wifi_only=1, sync_on_roaming=0, auto_upload_account_name=null}
03-26 18:21:24.770: D/PicasaSyncManager(1108): reject MetadataSyncTask (**************************) for wifi connection
03-26 18:21:24.830: D/dalvikvm(220): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5005K, 37% free 12850K/20359K, paused 35ms
03-26 18:21:24.850: D/dalvikvm(142): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1840K, 43% free 16283K/28295K, paused 3ms+10ms
03-26 18:21:24.870: D/AndroidRuntime(1175): Shutting down VM
03-26 18:21:24.870: D/dalvikvm(1175): GC_CONCURRENT freed 100K, 87% free 343K/2560K, paused 1ms+0ms
03-26 18:21:24.880: I/AndroidRuntime(1175): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
03-26 18:21:24.880: D/jdwp(1175): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
03-26 18:21:24.880: D/dalvikvm(1175): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
03-26 18:21:25.020: D/dalvikvm(220): GC_CONCURRENT freed 38K, 28% free 14806K/20359K, paused 2ms+3ms
03-26 18:21:25.040: D/AndroidRuntime(1189): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
03-26 18:21:25.040: D/AndroidRuntime(1189): CheckJNI is OFF
03-26 18:21:25.050: D/dalvikvm(220): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1909K, 37% free 12899K/20359K, paused 31ms
03-26 18:21:25.180: D/AndroidRuntime(1189): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
03-26 18:21:25.190: I/ActivityManager(142): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=BIQ.ERP/.BIQActivity } from pid 1189
03-26 18:21:25.190: W/ActivityManager(142): Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=BIQ.ERP/.BIQActivity } from null (pid=1189, uid=2000) requires android.permission.INTERNET
03-26 18:21:25.240: D/dalvikvm(220): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 27% free 14897K/20359K, paused 2ms+3ms
03-26 18:21:25.370: D/dalvikvm(220): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3136K, 33% free 13785K/20359K, paused 2ms+3ms
03-26 18:21:25.460: D/dalvikvm(220): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 755K, 28% free 14833K/20359K, paused 31ms
03-26 18:21:25.610: D/dalvikvm(220): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1058K, 23% free 15769K/20359K, paused 2ms+3ms
03-26 18:21:25.670: D/dalvikvm(672): GC_CONCURRENT freed 351K, 8% free 6977K/7559K, paused 2ms+2ms
03-26 18:21:25.760: D/dalvikvm(220): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1131K, 19% free 16631K/20359K, paused 2ms+3ms
03-26 18:21:29.370: I/ActivityManager(142): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=BIQ.ERP/.BIQActivity } from pid 220
03-26 18:21:29.370: W/ActivityManager(142): Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=BIQ.ERP/.BIQActivity } from ProcessRecord{40a88a00 220:com.android.launcher/10038} (pid=220, uid=10038) requires android.permission.INTERNET
03-26 18:21:29.380: E/Launcher(220): Launcher does not have the permission to launch Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=BIQ.ERP/.BIQActivity }. Make sure to create a MAIN intent-filter for the corresponding activity or use the exported attribute for this activity. tag=ApplicationInfo(title=BIQ) intent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=BIQ.ERP/.BIQActivity }
03-26 18:21:29.380: E/Launcher(220): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=BIQ.ERP/.BIQActivity } from ProcessRecord{40a88a00 220:com.android.launcher/10038} (pid=220, uid=10038) requires android.permission.INTERNET
03-26 18:21:29.380: E/Launcher(220):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1321)
03-26 18:21:29.380: E/Launcher(220):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1275)
03-26 18:21:29.380: E/Launcher(220):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1535)
03-26 18:21:29.380: E/Launcher(220):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1377)
03-26 18:21:29.380: E/Launcher(220):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3131)
03-26 18:21:29.380: E/Launcher(220):    at com.android.launcher2.Launcher.startActivityForResult(Launcher.java:1585)
03-26 18:21:29.380: E/Launcher(220):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3237)
03-26 18:21:29.380: E/Launcher(220):    at com.android.launcher2.Launcher.startActivitySafely(Launcher.java:2174)
03-26 18:21:29.380: E/Launcher(220):    at com.android.launcher2.AllAppsPagedView$1.run(AllAppsPagedView.java:314)
03-26 18:21:29.380: E/Launcher(220):    at com.android.launcher2.PagedView$1.onAnimationRepeat(PagedView.java:850)
03-26 18:21:29.380: E/Launcher(220):    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.animationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1094)
03-26 18:21:29.380: E/Launcher(220):    at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.handleMessage(ValueAnimator.java:632)
03-26 18:21:29.380: E/Launcher(220):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-26 18:21:29.380: E/Launcher(220):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
03-26 18:21:29.380: E/Launcher(220):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
03-26 18:21:29.380: E/Launcher(220):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 18:21:29.380: E/Launcher(220):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
03-26 18:21:29.380: E/Launcher(220):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
03-26 18:21:29.380: E/Launcher(220):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
03-26 18:21:29.380: E/Launcher(220):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-26 18:21:29.810: D/dalvikvm(1076): GC_EXPLICIT freed 48K, 5% free 6302K/6595K, paused 8ms+3ms
03-26 18:21:31.910: D/PowerManagerService(142): @PowerManagement: 'KEEP_SCREEN_ON_FLAG' releaseWakeLock when screen locked
03-26 18:21:34.790: D/dalvikvm(1083): GC_EXPLICIT freed 80K, 5% free 6312K/6595K, paused 5ms+2ms
03-26 18:21:39.790: D/dalvikvm(1108): GC_EXPLICIT freed 490K, 8% free 7032K/7623K, paused 4ms+2ms
03-26 18:21:44.810: D/dalvikvm(1131): GC_EXPLICIT freed 213K, 5% free 6411K/6727K, paused 6ms+2ms
03-26 18:21:49.800: D/dalvikvm(672): GC_EXPLICIT freed 226K, 10% free 6821K/7559K, paused 6ms+2ms
```

And this, apear at the console:

```
[2012-03-26 18:28:32 - BIQ] Android Launch!
[2012-03-26 18:28:32 - BIQ] adb is running normally.
[2012-03-26 18:28:32 - BIQ] Performing BIQ.ERP.BIQActivity activity launch
[2012-03-26 18:28:34 - BIQ] Uploading BIQ.apk onto device '37c70834240e197'
[2012-03-26 18:28:34 - BIQ] Installing BIQ.apk...
[2012-03-26 18:28:35 - BIQ] Success!
[2012-03-26 18:28:35 - BIQ] Starting activity BIQ.ERP.BIQActivity on device 37c70834240e197
[2012-03-26 18:28:36 - BIQ] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=BIQ.ERP/.BIQActivity }
[2012-03-26 18:28:36 - BIQ] ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=BIQ.ERP/.BIQActivity } from null (pid=1346, uid=2000) requires android.permission.INTERNET
```

Comment: Can you please show us AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: I already changed the api and the version to 3.2, in the eclipse.
But it still gives the same message: "the application is not installed."

Comment: Give us `logcat` output or the output of `Windows->Show View->Error log`

Comment: When a debug the app to my tablet, on error log don't show nothing. only that the app is installing, and than it was installed successfully. like it's show when i debug to the emulator. The LogCat more later, i post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could this be your issue?

> Activity permissions (applied to the  tag) restrict who can
>   start the associated activity. The permission is checked during
>   Context.startActivity() and Activity.startActivityForResult(); if the
>   caller does not have the required permission then SecurityException is
>   thrown from the call.

(from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html)

Maybe try taking all those `android:permission="..."` attributes out of your `<activity>` tags.

Your Logcat says:

```
03-26 18:21:29.370: W/ActivityManager(142): Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=BIQ.ERP/.BIQActivity } from ProcessRecord{40a88a00 220:com.android.launcher/10038} (pid=220, uid=10038) requires android.permission.INTERNET
03-26 18:21:29.380: E/Launcher(220): Launcher does not have the permission to launch Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=BIQ.ERP/.BIQActivity }. Make sure to create a MAIN intent-filter for the corresponding activity or use the exported attribute for this activity. tag=ApplicationInfo(title=BIQ) intent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=BIQ.ERP/.BIQActivity }
03-26 18:21:29.380: E/Launcher(220): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=BIQ.ERP/.BIQActivity } from ProcessRecord{40a88a00 220:com.android.launcher/10038} (pid=220, uid=10038) requires android.permission.INTERNET
```

I really think you need to take those Internet permissions out of all your Activities.  If you read the quote from the Developer Guide that I included above, I think you will see why.

Comment: but the app needs the permission to use internet. because i use ksoap. at least was what i find, on my searchs.

Comment: a friend of mine tried in his tablet and on his mobile phone, and can only install the app if he remove the kSOAP jar.
I placed a question about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845887/issue-with-using-ksoap-jar-when-install-my-app-on-a-real-android-device

Comment: You need the Internet permission for your app.  You don't need it on every Activity.

Comment: No?  I think that i need, on every screen(activity). :s

Comment: @Pepper If you give internet permission in uses-permission tag, on the top, you need not give it in every activity tag. try to remove the permissions from Activity tags and you should be fine

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried adding supports-screens?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    package="BIQ.ERP" 
    android:versionCode="1" 
    android:versionName="1.0" > 

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> 
    <supports-screens
          android:smallScreens="true"
          android:normalScreens="true"
          android:largeScreens="true"
          android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

...

Comment: I will try it.  later i give feedback. :)  Thank u.

Comment: The LogCat that i posted, is the result with this piece of code. :(

Answer (score 0):

Check your logCat.

Maybe your app requires a feature not available on your device

Comment: What kind of feature? I do not have the tablet here right now.
But I already know what I can search for. :)

Comment: for example MULTITOUCH, but does not appear in your Manifest. Does the tablet supports INTERNET? Best is to look into the logCat protocol. It states usually the reasons

Comment: Sure it supports. :)  is a Asus Eee Pad Transformer TF101. but later, I put all the information here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i don't know what i did.
but it already works in my tablet.

I remove the permission to the internet out, of all of activity's.
I put the piece of code, refering to support screens, and other things.

Magic.... :)

Thank u for all.

Here the Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="BIQ.ERP"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <supports-screens
      android:smallScreens="true"
      android:normalScreens="true"
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true" android:resizeable="true"/>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
    <uses-configuration android:reqFiveWayNav="false" android:reqKeyboardType="qwerty" android:reqNavigation="undefined" android:reqTouchScreen="finger" android:reqHardKeyboard="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".BIQActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Menu" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" android:label="@string/app_name">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".InsertHoras" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" android:label="@string/app_name">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".InsertDespesas" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" android:label="@string/app_name">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Mapa" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" android:label="@string/app_name">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Perfil" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" android:label="@string/app_name">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```